# How to view original location using source maps in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, source-maps

Source maps enabled in Chrome.
I'm able to browse through the original files.
[image: chrome-browse-js-files]
However I can't figure out how to go from the stack trace to the place of the error in the original files.

I am getting an error in my `all.min.js` file, containing all of my JS minified.
[image: chrome-debug-stack-trace]
I click the link in the stack trace and it takes me to this:
[image: chrome-minified-js]
How can I get to the location in the original file from here?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this feature hasn't been implemented or isn't possible.

Something that helps is clicking the `'un-minify' ('fix indent')` button in the bottom left corner of the code window.

[image]

That shows me where the error is happening in a more readable way, although it's simply an indentation fix.